# Reference Formula Cell and Modify Relative Cells

Tags: google-apps-script

So in Sheets using Script

I have a forumla say in D3

in D3 it says = UpdateRow()

What I want is in script UpdateRow() to get the fact that I was called from D3, then update say E3, F3, G3, etc.

Is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit calling argument from Sheets to `UpdateRow()`.

However, if you include `ROW()` as your argument for the custom function, you can then use this in the way you describe in the logic within the function.

```
=UpdateRow(COLUMN(),ROW())
```

Will obviously give you the column also.

Comment: Thanks then how do I set a relative column in the script say COLUMN()+1

Comment: Do you already have the `UpdateRow(col, row)` script written? In this case i.e. D > E,F & G you would use `.getRange(row, col + 1, 1, 3)` and then `.setValues(valE, valF, valG)`. Difficult to be more specific than that without context. Are these values not possible to update using formulas?

Comment: Discovered you cant update cells by reference. Only cell the formula is in or surrounding cells if you return an array

Comment: indeed - good catch. you can return an array of the values though